# Publication yammer post including html code with API

Tags: html, request, postman, yammer

I want to make a post on a yammer community, this post contains html code and I want my html code to be executed when posting to the community without being a group administrator, do you have any suggestions?

**When I use this query:**
https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json
**With these parameters:**

```
{
    "body": "<p>xxxxx <strong>paragraphe</strong> xxx</p>",
    "group_id": "1xxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

**the body will be displayed in the community with the tags HTML**

Answer (score 0):

Right now, I found only one way to display a body with a html format: via these 2 parameters:

"message_type": "announcement",
"is_rich_text": "true"

But that means you also spam the full community with your post.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).